# Compiled Assembly is not working

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I have a problem with a compiled assembly. It is not working if it is compiled on my build server. When I compile it local with the same configuration (Release|x86) like on build server, it will work correctly.
Now I have reflected the two Assemblies and see the following differences:

Not Working:

```
namespace Prayon.Entities
{
    using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
    using System;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;

    public class AccessProfileMap : ClassMap<AccessProfile>
    {
        public AccessProfileMap()
        {
            // ...
            base.Map((Expression<Func<AccessProfile, object>>) (x => x.Key));
            base.Map((Expression<Func<AccessProfile, object>>) (x => x.Name));
            base.Map((Expression<Func<AccessProfile, object>>) (x => x.Comment));
            base.Map((Expression<Func<AccessProfile, object>>) (x => x.Created));
        }
    }
}
```

Working (which is also my original code):

```
namespace Prayon.Entities
{
    using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
    using System;

    public class AccessProfileMap : ClassMap<AccessProfile>
    {
        public AccessProfileMap()
        {
            // ...
            base.Map(x => x.Key);
            base.Map(x => x.Name);
            base.Map(x => x.Comment);
            base.Map(x => x.Created);
        }
    }
}
```

Does someone have an idea, why the first one is not working? How can I prevent the replacement of the Linq-Expression while compiling?

Comment: What are the differences between your machine and the build server? Without that information it's really difficult to answer your question.

Comment: What error are you getting? If the method `base.Map` takes an `Expression` as argument (which it seems to be) the code must be equivalent.

Comment: Does both machines have the exact versions of any third party dlls/assemblies which your code is dependent on?

Comment: maybe on build server version of .net framework older than 3.5